# PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet import mysql from excel error charset

Tags: php, mysql, phpspreadsheet

My excel file contains Vietnamese data:

```
Tính tiền | Việt Nam
```

When I use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet to import data into mysql, error data likely "Tính ti?n" | "Vi?t Nam".
I have tried changing the code setInputEncoding like this:

```
$allowed_extension = array('xls', 'csv', 'xlsx');
$file_array = explode(".", $_FILES["import_excel"]["name"]);
$file_extension = end($file_array);
$file_name = time() . '.' . $file_extension;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['import_excel']['tmp_name'], $file_name);
$file_type = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($file_name);
$reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($file_type);

$reader->setInputEncoding('utf-8');
/$reader->setInputEncoding('CP1252');
```

It's still not working, I need help... Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You must look that utf8 is used see [FAQ](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/faq/#there-seems-to-be-a-problem-with-character-encoding) and [documentation](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/)

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the proper input encoding, whatever the spreadsheet has; for example:

```
$reader->setInputEncoding('CP1258');
```